# Count equal elements in R

Tags: r, count

I have x is:

`x<-c( 1, 2 , 3 , 1 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 3 , 8 )`

*How can i count the equal elements in x? I want the returned result as 3.*

**Explanation**: There are 3 values(1,2,3) that  appeared at least twice.

With x[i]==**1** there are **2** elements, count=**1**

With x[i]==**2** there are **3** elements, count=**2**

With x[i]==**3** there are **3** elements, count=**3**

I want the result is **count=3.**
Thank you very much!

Comment: `tb <- tabulate(x); length(tb[tb > 1])`

Answer (score 0):

So if I undestand well, you want to count how many numbers are repeated in the vector.

One way to do it would be to construct a table from the vector, and see how many elements have a count higher than one:

```r
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 2, 3, 8)
tab <- table(x)
sum(tab > 1)
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of base R options :

Using `rle` :

```
sum(with(rle(sort(x)), lengths > 1))
#[1] 3
```

With `tapply` :

```
sum(tapply(x, x, length) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

x<-c( 1, 2 , 3 , 1 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 3 , 8 )

tibble::tibble(x) %>% dplyr::count(x)
```

**Edit:**

As I was kindly asked to add some comments I will gladly do so.
Here I emplyoed packages **tibble** to create a data.frame (or tibble, rather) and the **dplyr** package for pivoting.

```
tibble::tibble(x)
```

turns the vector **x** into a tibble (type of data.frame) for further analysis. Unfortunately, the only variable of the tibble **x** is also called **x**. Sorry for that!

```
%>%
```

The pipe operator takes the value to its left (here, the newly created tibble called **x** ) and provides it as input for the subsequent command :

```
dplyr::count(x)
```

Here, we use **dplyr** to **count()** the variable **x** from the tibble **x** (again, sorry for that). The result will show which variables occured how many times:

```
      x     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     2
2     2     3
3     3     3
4     4     1
5     5     1
6     6     1
7     8     1
```

where the first column (1 to 7) are simply row numbers, **x** are the values provided by the original question and **n** counts how often each variable occured.

Answer (score 0):

```
length(unique(x[duplicated(x)]))
# 3
```

Data

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 2, 3, 8)
```